# How to disable Apache and MySQL autostart when PC is turned on?

Tags: apache-httpd, mysql

I'm using Linux Mint 18 XFCE and installed Apache, MySQL and PHP packages to make local development.

Apache and MySQL services are always active and start from the beginning.

How can I disable those service to do not start at the beginning? The idea is that whenever I want to work locally I'll start both services using something like:

```
sudo service apache2 start && sudo service mysql start
```

Comment: Remove them from init.d / systemd

Comment: I see no reason to downvote.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should disable them using either `systemctl` (if you're using systemd) or `update-rc.d`:

```
systemctl disable apache2 mysql
```

or

```
update-rc.d apache2 disable
update-rc.d mysql disable
```

Comment: It worked using `systemctl`.

Answer (score 3):

This may depend on your init system. Try one of these:

```
chkconfig apache2 off
systemctl disable apache2
insserv -r apache2
```